# Spells like Blockade to aid dungeoncrasher?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I have a dungeoncrasher with plenty of UMD and very little terrain.

I'm looking for the lowest-level spell that can generate solid terrain, preferably as a swift action, at a range further than Blockade's 0ft. My 'best' option so far is a 7th level Quickened Wall of Chains, which is rather terrible from a level standpoint, and rather overkill from a results standpoint.

Comment: Maybe simply use the floor instead of a wall; cast a Fly spell and crush your enemies from above ... :)

Comment: Certainly a possibility, though not entirely a practical one in my case. I'm most interested in terrain generation specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's possible to construct a small mobile wall of stone (5 ft square, but as a T-piece, so that it cannot fall or get pushed away) which lies within the size limits of the *Shrink Item Spell (PH, 279)*.

If you manage to do so, you could use the spell to shrink the mobile wall. Consider making it permanent with the *Permanency Spell* so that you can shrink and unshrink the wall for an indefinite number of times.

> Objects changed by a shrink item spell can be returned to normal
> composition and size merely by tossing them onto any solid surface or
> by a word of command from the original caster.

In order to speed that up and to let the wall appear at a convenient range you could use a quickened version of the 0-level *Spell Launch Item (Spell Compendium, 130)* making it a 4th level spell effectively. That would - as a swift action - give you a wall exactly where you need one.

Comment: I do have plenty of UMD indeed :P Isn't a Quicken spell a +4 level?

Comment: Oh, that's right. Sorry, I'll edit that.

Comment: I'll choose this answer as a pretty good one - the T-structure is a little finicky for my tastes (and would only work perfectly  from one side) but a different design, like a hollow square tube, could very well do the trick!

Comment: @ThanosMaravel A hollow square tube would definitely work better. I just came up with the T-structure idea because of the spell's size limits.

Answer (score 1):

You might try *Dark Way* from the *Spell Compendium* (p.58). It's level 2 instead of level 3, but is similarly a standard action. It only lasts 1r/lvl instead of the 1m/lvl found in *Wall of Chains*. It makes a shadow wall that is indestructible. Note, though, that if an object sets foot on the bridge that would exceed the weight tolerance, the offending object (and only the offending object) will pass through the bridge and fall as though the bridge were not there.

It's basically the poor man's wall of force, but it can only hold back things up to a certain weight.

Comment: Is it entirely RAW that stuff can crash into dark way?

Comment: @ThanosMaravel The spell's description, in part, says, "You create a ribbonlike, weightless, unbreakable bridge. **A *dark way*** must be anchored at both ends to solid objects, but otherwise **can be at any angle.**" Anchoring both ends and twisting the middle would create the effect described—or convincing the DM that the ends can be anchored *sideways* to opposing walls.

Comment: @ThanosMaravel yes. Literally the only thing that can penetrate the wall is an object that brings the weight being held by the wall over its limit. Otherwise, it stops literally everything and is indestructible.

Comment: That is a very problematic interpretation. It means it makes all wall spells obsolete a level before they start showing up. Especially considering it hinges on the DM approving it as something that you can twist, or anchor sideways, I don't see it as an option that could fly on any reasonable table. Using it as an unbreachable ceiling I can see, but that's all.